Implement Batch printing in Heidelberg - Prinect Cockpit
We have Heidelberg Versafier Pro (Ricoh Pro C7500). It uses Prinect Cockpit to manage the and control the printer jobs, printing and configuration.
I would like to implement the batch printing where one Heidelberg print job should print multiple files/artworks with their defined quantity of print copies and defined material/tray.
As we know the Heidelberg Versafier has multiple trays and can load different materials at once. For integration, it offers following integration techniques:

Hotfolder
CSV Hotfolder
JDF Hotfolder

Here is my scenario to implement it using CSV Hotfolder integration:
Injecting a CSV file containing one job with multiple files, and I need to ensure that each file is printed according to the following specifications and exact order:

File 1: A one-page PDF that should be printed 10 copies using tray1
or specific paper (White film label).
File 2: A one-page PDF that
should be printed 1 copy using tray2 or specific paper (plain white
paper).
File 3: A one-page PDF that should be printed 3 copies using
tray1 or specific paper (White film label).
File 4: A one-page PDF
that should be printed 1 copy using tray2 or specific paper (plain
white paper).

The operator only click print button and it should automatically print the job based on specified material, print copies and correct order of files.
The CSV file screenshot is attached.

If it is not possible with CSV, please share JDF sample to implement the above scenario.
https://onlinehelp.prinect-lounge.c...021/en_10/index.htm#t=Prinect/Start/Start.htm
https://onlinehelp.prinect-lounge.com/Prinect_Portal/Version2021/en_10/#t=Prinect/Start/Start.htm
